# Как выполнить bulk обновление в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Допустим, я беру данные из таблицы, произвожу вычисления. Дальше, сохраняю в массив.

Например:

```
[
  {id: 1, data: ...},
  {id: 134, data: ...}
  {id: 123114, data: ...}
]
```

Я могу не собирать в массив, а делать обновление сразу. Но ведь лучше порцианально, по 100, например, чем по одному, верно? Или лучше по одному?

Как сделать такое обновление на чистом SQL?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, если в MySQL, то зачем лишние теги? уберите. Во-вторых, вычисления - они тоже в MySQL? А массив - где? в MySQL массивов нет...

Comment: Массив? Например в JS, или в PHP. Мб еще где-то. Вопрос в том, как сделать несколько обновлений одним запросом, а не по O(n). P.S Простите, что за теги, не очень могу понять.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем было рассказывать про получение и обработку... всё ж просто - есть массив в программе, есть таблица в БД, надо обновить данные в таблице данными из массива. Пакетно. Но для осмысленного совета - мало данных... хотя бы точная версия MySQL - какая? записей для обновления - сколько?

Comment: в транзакцию заверните, prepare запросу сделайте с параметрами, и делайте в цикле по одному. Либо если много, то вставьте во временную таблицу и апдейт с джойном потом

Comment: И всё-таки это существенно - из какого ЯП вы к базе обращаетесь, и через какую библиотеку или ORM.

Comment: @CrazyElf, PHP, Wordpress. Там есть класс для бд (https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb). Но bulk update нет, так что raw sql.

Comment: @Akina, записей много. Обрабатываю порционно, по 100. Версия MySQL 5.

Comment: *записей много* Что, только до ста считать умеем? ну что за детский сад? 10 тысяч и 10 миллионов - это всё может быть "много", а подходов требует разных. *Версия MySQL 5* И 5,0, и 5,7 - это всё версия 5. А разница изрядная.

Comment: Допустим 10 миллионов. Сложно предсказать точнее, сколько будет у клиентов. Версия MySQL 5.7.38.